# Get a number from other html page

Tags: php, html

I want to get active connections number to compare with a set number to check if a server can handle more connections or that it should redirect to a other server.

Stat page of the server:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <pre>Active connections: 2 
server accepts handled requests
 208 208 232 
Reading: 0 Writing: 1 Waiting: 0 
</pre>
</body>

</html>​
```

I am looking for a code that put the '2' in this case in to a variable. Where I can work with.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the source of the file, remove html tags and use regex to find the value.

```
$html = strip_tags(File_get_contents("source.html"));
Preg_match("/Active connections:\s+(\d+)/", $html, $number);
```

Now `$number` is an array with the value.

Comment: Thanks for fast respons. Only when I do echo "<h2>$number</h2>; to check the number. It only displays 'Array'

Comment: Yes as I said it's an array. You need to echo it as an array. Read these two pages and it will be clear https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Here's a hint: https://3v4l.org/5Asn7 you need to know how arrays work that is why I'm not just writing out the answer. If you don't know what and how arrays work you can basically give up with programming.

Comment: Thanks, I have a lot to learn!

Comment: @KingHorse if you do not find out how to echo the number, just tell me and I will help you out. But you need the basic understanding of arrays. And just spoon-feeding the correct answer on basic stuff will not help you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, Everything does work great.